# MMDrawer Library in Swift Project for Side drawer, how to close drawer?

Tags: swift, mmdrawercontroller

I am using MMDrawer Obj C library to open left drawer in my Swift project, Everything works fine, but while tapping on CenterVC, nothing happens(it is not closing drawer), earlier in obj C project, it is working fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079150/mmdrawercontroller-cant-close-drawer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an action and then add the code to close the drawer. like tap gesture.

This answer shows the code that closes the drawer.

[Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079150/mmdrawercontroller-cant-close-drawer)